# I am trying to solve numbers of islands problem on Leetcode but runtime error is occurring ,can anybody help in this code?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

By using dfs algorithm I am trying to visit every island and how many times dfs function is called
is no. of the island, I took visited vector for marking down the places where I am already visited. Grid is containing 0's and 1's. 0 means water, and 1 means land. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

```
void dfs( vector<vector<int>> &vis,vector<vector<char>>& grid,int di[],int dj[],int i,int j,int n,int m)
   {
       if(vis[i][j]==1||grid[i][j]=='0')
       return;
       //   int ind=0;
       for(int ind=0;ind<4;ind++)
       {
           vis[i][j]=1;
           int ni=i+di[ind];
           int nj=j+di[ind];
           if(ni>=0&&nj>=0 && ni<n && nj<m && !vis[ni][nj]&&grid[ni][nj]=='1')
           dfs(vis,grid,di,dj,ni,nj,n,m);
           vis[ni][nj]=1;
       } 
       
   }
    
    
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
       
        int n=grid.size();
        
        int c=0;
        int m=grid[0].size();
        
        vector<vector<int>> vis(n,vector<int>(m,0));
        
        int di[4]={-1,0,0,+1,};
        int dj[4]={0,+1,-1,0};
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
             for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
             {        
                 if(grid[i][j]=='1' && !vis[i][j])
                 {   
                    
                     dfs(vis,grid,di,dj,i,j,n,m);
                     c++;
                     
                 }
             }
        }
        return c;
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Without knowing what inputs are causing the error, or even what the error is, there isn't really anything people here can do to help.

Comment: [["1","1","0","0","0"],
["1","1","0","0","0"],
["0","0","1","0","0"],
["0","0","0","1","1"]]